# Extracting embeddings from a keras neural network's intermediate layer

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, word2vec, feature-extraction

I have this neural network based on [this](https://www.kaggle.com/code/haibaral/spanish-word2vec)

```
words_input = Input(shape=(500,),dtype='int32',name='words_input')
words = Embedding(input_dim=wordEmbeddings.shape[0], output_dim=wordEmbeddings.shape[1], weights=[wordEmbeddings], trainable=False)(words_input)
conv_1 = Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=10, strides=2, activation='relu')(words)
avgpool_1 = AveragePooling1D(pool_size=10, strides=10)(conv_1)
b_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(200, activation='tanh', return_sequences=False))(avgpool_1)
dense_1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(b_lstm)
dropout = Dropout(0.1)(dense_1)
dense_2 = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(dropout)


sgd = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model = Model(inputs=words_input, outputs=dense_2)
extractor = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.get_layer(words).output)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
```

I added the line

```
extractor = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.get_layer(words).output)
```

cause I want to extract the word2vec embeddings of the words from the inputs like they show [here](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer-feature-extraction)

But I'm getting this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_6732/2108362002.py in <module>
     11 sgd = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
     12 model = Model(inputs=words_input, outputs=dense_2)
---> 13 extractor = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.get_layer(words).output)
     14 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
     15 model.summary()

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in get_layer(self, name, index)
   3271         if name is not None:
   3272             for layer in self.layers:
-> 3273                 if layer.name == name:
   3274                     return layer
   3275             raise ValueError(

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151     except Exception as e:
    152       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154     finally:
    155       del filtered_tb

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/core/tf_op_layer.py in handle(self, op, args, kwargs)
    117             for x in tf.nest.flatten([args, kwargs])
    118         ):
--> 119             return TFOpLambda(op)(*args, **kwargs)
    120         else:
    121             return self.NOT_SUPPORTED

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.__operators__.eq" (type TFOpLambda).

Expected float32 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Equal', got 'words_input' of type 'str' instead. Error: Expected float32, but got words_input of type 'str'.

Call arguments received by layer "tf.__operators__.eq" (type TFOpLambda):
  • self=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 500, 300), dtype=float32)
  • other='words_input'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Why is it passing the name of the first layer "words_input" to the parameter y? Which is what I assume it is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the correct name to the get_layer of the model, try this code

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
words_input = keras.Input(shape=(500,),dtype='int32',name='words_input')
words = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=wordEmbeddings.shape[0], output_dim=wordEmbeddings.shape[1], weights=[wordEmbeddings], trainable=False, name='words')(words_input)
conv_1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=10, strides=2, activation='relu')(words)
avgpool_1 = keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=10, strides=10)(conv_1)
b_lstm = keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(200, activation='tanh', return_sequences=False))(avgpool_1)
dense_1 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(b_lstm)
dropout = keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(dense_1)
dense_2 = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(dropout)


sgd = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model = keras.Model(inputs=words_input, outputs=dense_2)
extractor = keras.Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.get_layer('words').output)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
```

```
extractor.summary()

Output:
```

[image]